# C++ check for valid date time format

Tags: c++, validation, datetime, format

Whats a good way to check a date format, i want the format to be 2011-12-08 16:59:18 I have boost would using regex be the best way to go or is there some C++ way of doing it. Thanks in advance. here are some test conditions but not limited to these.

So for example someone enters

```
2011-2-08 16:59:18 //incorrect date month needs to have 2 digits 02
2011-02-08 16:9:18  //incorrect minuets needs to have 2 digits 09
2011-02-0X 16:09:18 //incorect alpha character for day no alpha except - and :
2011-12-08 16:59:18 // correct
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions would work, or you could just walk the string and test each character to be sure it is what you expect it to be. You will probably spend less time doing the latter.

Comment: And probably it would be more efficient then regex version.

Comment: A simple regex might catch obvious errors but for stuff like handling Feb month ... Leap years etc might be too much for a regex

Comment: I just did a simple loop through each character and checked isNumeric seems to work for me. Thanks all

Comment: Wait, even on the punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strptime.html)** to convert a date from string format to a tm structure.

Also you can use **[Boost Date Time Input/Output](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html)**